# Pass a cookie down into an iframe (with 3rd party cookies disabled) through an untrusted domain

Tags: javascript, security, cryptography

Here's an scenario we're running into.

Let's say we have:

- Some untrusted domain, `untrusted.com`
- Our trusted domain, `trusted.com`, that we have full control over

The following things are given:

- `untrusted.com` has a javascript script on its page, loaded from `trusted.com` -- so `trusted.com` has complete control over the front-end javascript context of `untrusted.com`
- This javascript file creates an iframe on the `untrusted.com` page, pointed to `trusted.com`
- The user's browser is in 3rd-party-cookies-disabled mode, so the iframe has **no access to any of the cookies set on `trusted.com`**
- We want to make the session-cookie from `trusted.com` available within the iframe
- We absolutely can't allow `untrusted.com` to see the value of this session-cookie
- We can't just encrypt it and pass it through `untrusted.com`, because that would allow `untrusted.com` to intercept it and replay it

So the question is, how do we get that session-cookie down in such a way that:

a) We are 100% sure `untrusted.com` **is not replaying it**

b) We are 100% sure `untrusted.com` **can't read** the original value of the cookie

Comment: the top page can't see variables or cookie inside the iframe or it's page.

Comment: Yep, I know that. The problem I have is that I want to be able to pass the cookie down manually in some way *through* the parent page. This is a situation where the frame is in 3rd party cookies disabled mode, so it can't access cookies by itself.

Comment: a long time ago for security, kings would hire scribes who knew how to write but not read (yes that's possible), but there is nothing like that in JS: if you give something to someone, they can see it, why not just print the info into the framed page instead of using cookies?

Comment: Remember that the JavaScript loaded from `trusted.com` will not have access to the user's cookies on `trusted.com` because this JavaScript request will be classed as a 3rd party request. The only way round this is to open a popup, which would require the user to click in order to defeat popup blockers. Then you have the problem of passing the session identifier from the popup into the IFrame, which I expect the [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) to block. Messy, and I don't think it'd work.

Comment: Yeah. Bear in mind we have control over `trusted.com` server side, so if we need to enable a CORS or JSONP endpoint we can do that. Still not sure what we'd have it return though.